# Struts2 + Internationalization + Java

Tags: java, internationalization

I am using Struts2 Internationalization to support English & Arabic.

I want to know that is it possible to dynamically or automatically change the position of label which comes before any input (text, date, etc.) when the locale changes?

E.g.

LTR -> English -> First Name - "Input Text Box"

RTL -> Arabic -> "Input Text Box" - أول اسم

Any possible solution for this?

BR
SC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Either* (ab)use [`java.awt.ComponentOrientation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/ComponentOrientation.html)

```
String direction = ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(locale).isLeftToRight() ? "ltr" : "rtl";
```

(its source code is pretty trivial though, there are only 4 languages which are RTL, here's an extract of relevance)

```
public static ComponentOrientation getOrientation(Locale locale) {
    String lang = locale.getLanguage();
    if ("iw".equals(lang) || "ar".equals(lang) || "fa".equals(lang) || "ur".equals(lang)) {
        return RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
    } else {
        return LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
    }
}
```

*Or* put it in a recourcebundle yourself.

```
this.direction = ltr
```

And read it as follows

```
String direction = bundle.getString("this.direction");
```

---

Either way, you can make use of this to change the direction accordingly.

```
<html dir="${direction}">
```

which would end up as `<html dir="ltr">` or `<html dir="rtl">` in generated HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I have added "this.direction" to my both of the resource bundles 'en' and 'ar'. And I am using at table level like this "<table align=center class="" dir="${direction}">". But this doesn't work. Am I missing some thing? Do I need to extend some class? Please elaborate that part, I want that to be changed when I switch locale. BR SC

Comment: Do you have set the `${direction}`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. But where do I need to set it? Inside jsp? Or through some other way? BR. SC.

Comment: That was a plain JSP/Servlet example. In Struts2 you could probably do `<table dir="<bean:message key="this.direction">">`.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Not sure what i am doing wrong, but I have tried using JSTL: [ <table dir="<fmt:message key="registration.direction"/>"> ] and when page renders it shows this [dir="???registration.direction???"]. I have properties file namely "registration_en.properties" & "registration_ar.properties". I totally cant understand what is issue. My other internationalization is working fine from same resource bundles. Thanks for your help and cooperation. BR. SC

Comment: I see that you asked a new question about this. Please continue there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667724/jstl-fmtmessage-and-resource-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know.

Messages can be localised and have arguments to handle currencies symbols and the like, but I have not seen any ready-made available framework that can handle left-to-right and right-to-left ordering of page.

My guess is that you have to serve pages, parts of pages using tiles or write the if else statements by your self.