# Struts2 + Internationalization + Arabic + English + {RTL or LTR}

Tags: internationalization, struts2

I am still struggling with formatting (LTR or RTL) the output with respect to language English or Arabic.

Lets take simple one tag of "struts-tag" library:

```
<s:textfield key="_do._toTime" value="00:00" maxlength="5"/>
```

Now I want that when locale is "English" it should print "LTR" but when locale is "Arabic" it should print "RTL".

I read some where that its possible but couldn't find any concrete example that how to achieve this?

Any idea?

BR
SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you were on the right track in your previous question:
[Struts2 + Internationalization + Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659263/struts2-internationalization-java)

The easiest way to adapt BalusC's example is to add a `getDirection()` method to your action which returns either "ltr" or "rtl".

```
public String getDirection() {
    return getText("this.direction");
}
```

Then, in your JSP:

```
<html dir="${action.direction}">
```

That will trigger the `getDirection()` method on your action, which will return the value of this.direction in your bundle.

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks... It worked... !!! Yup the BalusC's example also helped...  BR. SC.